# KVM - Problem installing Windows 2003 guest on Debian Lenny 64bit Host

Tags: windows-server-2003, debian, kvm-virtualization

I have a Debian Lenny 64bit host and had kvm installed with a windows 2003 working just fine but i noticed how old the kvm version in the standard packages was so I decided to update using debian backports to get more upto date packages.  So i updated using

apt-get -t lenny-backports install kvm libvirt-bin virtinst

So now i have

```
debian:~# virsh version
Compiled against library: libvir 0.8.3
Using library: libvir 0.8.3
Using API: QEMU 0.8.3
Running hypervisor: QEMU 0.9.1
```

so now I'm trying to setup a new guest with:

```
debian:/tmp# virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n win2k3 -r 2048 -c /home/win2k3.iso -f /home/win2k3.img -s 20 --nonetworks --noautoconsole --vnc --os-type=windows --os-variant=win2k3 --hvm --accelerate --debug
Sat, 04 Dec 2010 17:20:24 DEBUG    Launched with command line:
/usr/bin/virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n win2k3 -r 2048 -c /home/win2k3.iso -f /home/win2k3.img -s 20 --nonetworks --noautoconsole --vnc --os-type=windows --os-variant=win2k3 --hvm --accelerate --debug
Sat, 04 Dec 2010 17:20:24 DEBUG    Requesting libvirt URI qemu:///system
Sat, 04 Dec 2010 17:20:24 DEBUG    Received libvirt URI qemu:///system
Sat, 04 Dec 2010 17:20:24 DEBUG    Requesting virt method 'hvm', hv type 'default'.
Sat, 04 Dec 2010 17:20:24 DEBUG    Received virt method 'hvm'
Sat, 04 Dec 2010 17:20:24 DEBUG    Hypervisor name is 'kvm'
Sat, 04 Dec 2010 17:20:24 DEBUG    Could not open "/etc/sysconfig/keyboard" [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/sysconfig/keyboard'
Sat, 04 Dec 2010 17:20:24 DEBUG    Could not open "/etc/X11/xorg.conf": [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/X11/xorg.conf' 
Sat, 04 Dec 2010 17:20:24 DEBUG    Could not open "/etc/default/keyboard": [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/etc/default/keyboard' 
Sat, 04 Dec 2010 17:20:24 DEBUG    Did not parse any usable keymapping.
Sat, 04 Dec 2010 17:20:24 DEBUG    DistroInstaller location is a local file/path: /home/win2k3.iso


Starting install...
Creating storage file win 100% |=========================|  20 GB    00:00     
Sat, 04 Dec 2010 17:20:24 DEBUG    Generated install XML: 
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>win2k3</name>
  <currentMemory>2097152</currentMemory>
  <memory>2097152</memory>
  <uuid>d0bd8a0f-af7f-1647-4662-f4e3f86ef524</uuid>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='cdrom'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/><apic/><pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset="localtime"/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>destroy</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>destroy</on_crash>
  <vcpu>1</vcpu>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/win2k3.img'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu'/>
      <source file='/home/win2k3.iso'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
    </disk>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' keymap='en-us'/>
    <console type='pty'/>
    <video>
      <model type='vga'/>
    </video>
  </devices>
</domain>

Creating domain...                                                 0 B 00:00 
Sat, 04 Dec 2010 17:20:24 DEBUG    Started guest, looking to see if it is running
Sat, 04 Dec 2010 17:20:24 DEBUG    Generated boot XML: 
<domain type='kvm'>
  <name>win2k3</name>
  <currentMemory>2097152</currentMemory>
  <memory>2097152</memory>
  <uuid>d0bd8a0f-af7f-1647-4662-f4e3f86ef524</uuid>
  <os>
    <type arch='x86_64'>hvm</type>
    <boot dev='hd'/>
  </os>
  <features>
    <acpi/><apic/><pae/>
  </features>
  <clock offset="localtime"/>
  <on_poweroff>destroy</on_poweroff>
  <on_reboot>restart</on_reboot>
  <on_crash>restart</on_crash>
  <vcpu>1</vcpu>
  <devices>
    <emulator>/usr/bin/kvm</emulator>
    <disk type='file' device='disk'>
      <driver name='qemu' type='raw'/>
      <source file='/home/win2k3.img'/>
      <target dev='hda' bus='ide'/>
    </disk>
    <disk type='file' device='cdrom'>
      <driver name='qemu'/>
      <source file='/home/win2k3.iso'/>
      <target dev='hdc' bus='ide'/>
      <readonly/>
    </disk>
    <input type='tablet' bus='usb'/>
    <graphics type='vnc' port='-1' keymap='en-us'/>
    <console type='pty'/>
    <video>
      <model type='vga'/>
    </video>
  </devices>
</domain>

Domain installation does not appear to have been
 successful.  If it was, you can restart your domain
 by running 'virsh start win2k3'; otherwise, please
 restart your installation.
```

shows error but i dont see any reason why so i try

```
debian:/tmp# virsh start win2k3
Domain win2k3 started
```

then nothing starts and log shows

```
LC_ALL=C PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin HOME=/root USER=root LOGNAME=root QEMU_AUDIO_DRV=none /usr/bin/kvm -S -M pc-0.12 -enable-kvm -m 2048 -smp 1,sockets=1,cores=1,threads=1 -name win2k3 -uuid faaa37da-7eb3-d5ab-e36a-c7f782c5a657 -nodefaults -chardev socket,id=monitor,path=/var/lib/libvirt/qemu/win2k3.monitor,server,nowait -mon chardev=monitor,mode=readline -rtc base=localtime -boot c -drive file=/home/win2k3.img,if=none,id=drive-ide0-0-0,boot=on,format=raw -device ide-drive,bus=ide.0,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-0-0,id=ide0-0-0 -drive file=/home/win2k3.iso,if=none,media=cdrom,id=drive-ide0-1-0,readonly=on,format=raw -device ide-drive,bus=ide.1,unit=0,drive=drive-ide0-1-0,id=ide0-1-0 -chardev pty,id=serial0 -device isa-serial,chardev=serial0 -usb -device usb-tablet,id=input0 -vnc 127.0.0.1:0 -k en-us -vga std -device virtio-balloon-pci,id=balloon0,bus=pci.0,addr=0x3 
char device redirected to /dev/pts/6
exception 13 (0)
rax 0000000000000010 rbx 000000000000c000 rcx 0000000000006e36 rdx 00000000c0000000
rsi 0000000000000003 rdi 0000000000000000 rsp 0000000000006e2c rbp 0000000000000008
r8  0000000000000000 r9  0000000000000000 r10 0000000000000000 r11 0000000000000000
r12 0000000000000000 r13 0000000000000000 r14 0000000000000000 r15 0000000000000000
rip 00000000000fec3c rflags 00033002
cs 0000 (00000000/0000ffff p 1 dpl 3 db 0 s 1 type 3 l 0 g 0 avl 0)
ds 0000 (00000000/0000ffff p 1 dpl 3 db 0 s 1 type 3 l 0 g 0 avl 0)
es 0000 (00000000/0000ffff p 1 dpl 3 db 0 s 1 type 3 l 0 g 0 avl 0)
ss 0000 (00000000/0000ffff p 1 dpl 3 db 0 s 1 type 3 l 0 g 0 avl 0)
fs 0000 (00000000/0000ffff p 1 dpl 3 db 0 s 1 type 3 l 0 g 0 avl 0)
gs 0000 (00000000/0000ffff p 1 dpl 3 db 0 s 1 type 3 l 0 g 0 avl 0)
tr 0000 (feffd000/00002088 p 1 dpl 0 db 0 s 0 type b l 0 g 0 avl 0)
ldt 0000 (00000000/0000ffff p 1 dpl 0 db 0 s 0 type 2 l 0 g 0 avl 0)
gdt f7a30/37
idt f8ab0/0
cr0 10 cr2 0 cr3 0 cr4 0 cr8 0 efer 0
code: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 --> 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
```

I'm just not sure where to go.  Any help would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after reading more on http://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Code#Debian they say "It is important to use more recent kernel - 2.6.26 does not work well with kvm"

so I ran below since I have 64bit (linux-image-2.6-686 for 32bit)

apt-get -t lenny-backports install linux-image-2.6-amd64

then rebooted and tried to create my vm again and it WORKED!

```
debian:~# virt-install --connect qemu:///system -n win2k3 -r 2048 -c /home/win2k3.iso -f /home/win2k3.img -s 20 --nonetworks --noautoconsole --vnc --os-type=windows --os-variant=win2k3 --hvm --accelerate


Starting install...
Creating storage file win 100% |=========================|  20 GB    00:00     
Creating domain...                                                 0 B 00:00 
Domain installation still in progress. Waiting for installation to complete.
```

I hope this helps anyone who might stumble here.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding @Brandon answer: 
Windows Server 2003 (for Small Businesses), stuck at the very end of the installation, if you start with `--nonetworks` (in 2016: `--network none`), 
displaying an error message, that you are required to install a TCP/IP capable network adapter.

It is better strategy to install with [usermode (local LAN) networking](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Networking#Usermode_Networking), then disable internet access of the machine through iptables.

I usually start like this:

`sudo virt-install \
--connect qemu:///system \
--name=win2k3-br1 \
--ram=1024 \
--vcpus=2 \
--os-type=windows --os-variant=win2k3 \
--virt-type=kvm \
--hvm \
--graphics vnc,port=5951 \
--cdrom=/var/lib/libvirt/boot/w2003cd1.iso \
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/win2k3-br1.img,size=10 \
--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/boot/virtio-win_x86.vfd,device=floppy \
--network=network:default,model=virtio`

To attach a 'monitor' to your machine I use vnc, with ssh port forwarding:

`ssh user@[IP of KVM master] -L 5951:127.0.0.1:5951
then start a vnc client (I use vinagre) locally and connect to 127.0.0.1:5951`

Don't forget to download the windows 2003 SCSI driver ([virtio-win_x86.vfd](https://fedorapeople.org/groups/virt/virtio-win/direct-downloads/stable-virtio/virtio-win_x86.vfd)), and press `F6` before the installation starts, and add it manually (real challenge to start a vnc client and press the F6), 
otherwise the installation stuck at 33 minutes remaining for indefinietly.

A small remark (in ubuntu 16.04.1, 2016 october), if I use qcow2 disk image format (`--disk path=/var/lib/libvirt/images/win2k3.qcow2,size=40,bus=virtio,format=qcow2`) the installation stuck also.